# About jQuery add image with classes

Tags: jquery, css, typescript

Okay let's go to jQuery, using classes for this looks more dynamic... So add classes according to the effects, and that should add a background to the div.

```
const iconHover = function() {
    const moveLeft = -305;
    const moveDown = 3;

    if (setup.battle.enemies[0]) {
        setup.battle.enemies[0].tempEffect.forEach((effect: effectInterface, index: number) => {
            const _icon = $('#grid-item-' + index);

            _icon.addClass(effect.iconClass)
        });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        $('#grid-item-' + i).hover(() => {
            $('div#icon_' + i).show()
        }, function() {
            $('div#icon_' + i).hide()
        })

        $('#grid-item-' + i).mousemove(event => {
            $("div#icon_" + i)
                .css('top', event.pageY + moveDown)
                .css('left', event.pageX + moveLeft)
        })
    }
}
```

This theoretically works, considering that it adds the class to the desired element, which is a grid of effect icons for the characters.

```
<div class="iconContainer">
        <div id="grid-item-0"></div>
        <div id="grid-item-1"></div>
        <div id="grid-item-2"></div>
        <div id="grid-item-3"></div>
        <div id="grid-item-4"></div>
</div>
```

The classes are properly added to the icon divs, and the src image returns correctly.

```
.superiorFlame {
    background: url("img/icons/superiorFlame.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

However within the div, even with the class, this does not seem to work.

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArtkD.png)

The grid console.log, with the element added.

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTEMw.png)

Comment: `This theoretically works`,  but its not ok, how we could help you without minimun code functional....https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added additional information.

Comment: you are sure  effect.iconclass has the right value -> superiorFlame? could you display console.log

Comment: Yes, this adds the correct class to the icon divs, I added the console image. So I mentioned, in theory, this should be showing the image of the icon, but I may be missing something.

Comment: without seing the code about id #icon, could you see my answer..

Comment: And if you specify manually in  the html code, the right class and the style , tou have the result waited?  to be sure that the problem is comming from your program and not other problem css for example

Answer (score 0):

Its not a solution, i delete after if no solution,  but its easier to show code
it seems the problem is coming from the bind mousemove, could you comment the bind and see what happened..

```
    $('#grid-item-' + i).mousemove(event => {
        $("div#icon_" + i)
            .css('top', event.pageY + moveDown)
            .css('left', event.pageX + moveLeft)
    })
```

Comment: Oh, this excerpt is not about the image of the icons, this refers to the placement of the comment divs. The "div#icon_" stuff and the image stuff are unrelated things. Without that, basically the comment divs as I posted in the second image are fixed on the screen.